# PHP function which executes provided function with provided arguments

Tags: php

Is the a way in php to create a function which executes provided function (as an arguments) with provided argument (of the provided function - as an array).

Here is some code:

```
class Worker
{
    public function execute($func, $paramsArr)
    {
        php_func_executer($func, $paramsArr); //the function that I would like to have
    }
}
```

in other php file I will do as follow:

```
Class SomeClass 
{
    public function test($varA, $varB)
    {
         //do something
    }

    public function exeText()
    {
       ...
       $worker = new Worker();
       $worker->execute(test, [$varA, $varB]);
    }
}
```

I know about `call_user_func_array` but here I don't want to pass the name of the function (as string), I want to pass the function itself (as seen in the code above)

Thanks!

Comment: first argument of `call_user_func_array` is any callable, so you can pass a function to it, not name only.

Comment: even if it is not in the same file? the second argument is an array of arguments?

Comment: You should explain what do you mean by passing a function? You don;t want to pass a string with function name, so what do you want to pass - array? variable with anonymous function or what?

Comment: You can see in my second code block what I meant, but I think the answer is already posted here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the function name as a string and call it.

```
function execute($func, $paramsArr)
    {
        $func($paramsArr[0], $paramsArr[1]);
    }

function func($par1, $par2)
    {
        echo $par1." ".$par2;
    }


execute('func' , array('a','b'));
```

Answer (score 1):

call_user_func_array will do the job

```
$func = function($a, $b) {
    return $a+$b;
};

echo call_user_func_array($func, [1, 2]); // 3
```

Comment: I downvoted this because OP said this : `I know about call_user_func_array but here I don't want to pass the name of the function (as string), I want to pass the function itself (as seen in the code above)`. So this is not an answer to the question